# Laravel Carbon format wrong date

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I'm using Laravel and Carbon to format dates.

I have this code:

```
print_r($data['date']); //Saturday, 11 Jan, 2020
$data['date'] = Carbon::parse($data['date'])->format('Y-m-d');
dd($data['date']);
```

but the output is:

> Saturday, 11 Jan, 2020
>
> "2019-01-12"

As you can see 2020 is converted to 2019... Why? How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Laravel, but the standard DateTime parser does not understand the format `Saturday, 11 Jan, 2020`. You'll have to explicitly tell the parser how to parse the string. Something like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j M, Y', $data['date'])->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works fine but it's very strange because with "Saturday, 11 Jan, 2019" is converted using Carbon in 2019-01-11 ...

Comment: It's interpreting the 2020 as hours and minutes, i.e., 20:20. The resulting date is 2019 because the parser can't find a year so it defaults to the current year.

Comment: Note that `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz)` should work as well.