# Laravel 8: why is sorting by date in eloquent is wrong, using Carbon

Tags: laravel, chart.js, php-carbon

Possible duplicates:
[Laravel: How to order date, change the date format and group by the date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69160833/laravel-how-to-order-date-change-the-date-format-and-group-by-the-date)
[Laravel Carbon format wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59237813/laravel-carbon-format-wrong-date)

I created a line chart using chartjs, the chart and data fetching is working fine. However the order of the dates is wrong. It starts off with `Aug 2022` instead of `Jan 2022`.

- When I use the `orderBy()`, it shows  `orderBy() doesn't exists` error.
- When I use `createFromFormat()` of `Carbon`, it shows `missing data` error.

Why? I parsed the date with `Carbon` and the column type is `datetime`, shouldn't it be working?

[image]

This is my laravel collection:

```
$data = TrafficViolation::select('id', 'violationDateTime')
            ->get()
            ->sortBy('violationDateTime')
            ->groupBy(function($data) {
                return Carbon::parse($data['violationDateTime'])->format('M, Y');
            });
```

Comment: because get method return Collection<all-data> object ...

Answer (score 3):

The `orderBy()` is a **[Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)** method. Once you call `get()`, you get a **[Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#introduction)** instance.

To order the records in your DB you need to call `orderBy()` first, and than `get()`:

**UPDATE:**
I have included the records count, and date format. You still need to order the records by the **violationDateTime** column

```php
$data = User::selectRaw('COUNT(*) as violation_count, DATE_FORMAT(violationDateTime, \'%M, %Y\') as formatedDate')
            ->groupBy('formatedDate')
            ->orderBy('violationDateTime')
            ->get();
```

if your get a `Syntax error or access violation: 1055` you need to change the stritc mode in mysql to **false** in `/config/database.php` change `['connections' => ['mysql' => ['strict' => false]]]`

Comment: Understood. However even with ```orderBy()``` it's still showing August first... I tried ASC and DESC order, they all order correctly except August is always the first.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMushref Have you try running the query directly in the DB to see what records you get? If the order is correct as you say, are any other record in the table with a `violationDateTime` before August not getting retrieved by the query?

Comment: Yes, this is the result https://snipboard.io/cWJFk8.jpg

Comment: In that example you are ordering by formatedDate which is a string. So they are sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanMushref I updated my answer, please tried and let me know.

Comment: @AlanReed You're right! I didn't notice that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and apologies for late reply. Actually, I tried removing August jus to test...turns out that it always starts with the latest date...August not there? then start from July and so on...Spent these days trying to find out what the heck is going on